# Mongoose returning empty objects when populating all?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Hello I'm new to mongoose and I was trying to recreate a situation where a shift is assigned to a person. I've create the schemas

```
    var shiftSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: Date,
    location: String,
    job: String,
    event: String,
    calltime: Number,
    hours: Number
});

var Shift = mongoose.model("Shift", shiftSchema);

var memberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    secondaryid: Number,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    profile: String,
    active: Boolean,
    shifts: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Shift"
    }]
});

var Member = mongoose.model("Member", memberSchema);
```

and created two members and each one was pushed a shift.

```
//Members in DB
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bb14deb574f2b0d627c7ae2"), "shifts" : [ ObjectId("5bb14deb574f2b0d627c7ae3") ], "id" : 1000001, "secondaryid" : 20000001, "firstname" : "Jane", "lastname" : "Doe", "profile" : "Admin", "active" : true, "__v" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bb14e13f445e50d7ba0257d"), "shifts" : [ ObjectId("5bb14e9f19e7670d91478323") ], "id" : 1000000, "secondaryid" : 20000000, "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Doe", "profile" : "Admin", "active" : true, "__v" : 1 }

//Shifts in DB
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bb14deb574f2b0d627c7ae3"), "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "location" : "Office2", "job" : "Clerk2", "event" : "", "calltime" : 7, "hours" : 7, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bb14e9f19e7670d91478323"), "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"), "location" : "Office", "job" : "Clerk", "event" : "", "calltime" : 8, "hours" : 8, "__v" : 0 }
```

The problem is that when I run the following

```
Member.find({}).populate('shifts').exec(function(err, allMembers){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(allMembers)
    }
})
```

I get a response from DB but "shifts" has empty objects

```
[ { shifts: [ [Object] ],
    _id: 5bb14deb574f2b0d627c7ae2,
    id: 1000001,
    secondaryid: 20000001,
    firstname: 'Jane',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    profile: 'Admin',
    active: true,
    __v: 1 },
  { shifts: [ [Object] ],
    _id: 5bb14e13f445e50d7ba0257d,
    id: 1000000,
    secondaryid: 20000000,
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Doe',
    profile: 'Admin',
    active: true,
    __v: 1 } ]
```

What am I doing wrong? or do I need to loop through each and populate individually?

Comment: How do you know that they are empty?

Answer (score 0):

Thats a missunderstanding. If you log a bigger tree, `console.log` doesn't show the whole tree cause that would be overwhelming but instead it only shows three nested objects deep, so the following js object:

```
 { a: { b: { c: { d: { e: 1 } } } }
```

gets displayed as:

```
 { a: { b: { c: [Object] } } }
```

So actually the object isn't empty, its just not shown.